# text spacing of tables numbers in list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents

I just use documentclass(report) and \listoftables. And my tables in the documents have so long names for section name, like III.3.1.1 , and so on. So, when i compile the tex file, it became like this :
[image]

any idea to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE. Your problem is not only the  long text but also the numbering of the tables, using roman figures and arabic figures. See the `tocloft` package and `\cfttabnumwidth` for a change. By the way: We have this question basically every other day ...

Comment: ah thank you for the link. I have any idea what to search before.

Comment: Yes, searching can be a little bit frustrating here on TeX.SE...

Comment: sure, it can be a little bit frustrating if you do not know the term of something that you want to search about.